# Look for value in a table column that is made up of two database fields

Tags: javascript, angular, search

I have a table column composed in Angular in the following way:

```
        <tr *ngFor="let activity of activitiesTable.data">
              <td data-cy="employee-cell">
                   {{ activity.employee.lastName }} {{ activity.employee.firstName }}
              </td>
```

My research is implemented like this:

```
export function activityEmployeesFilterFn(
  entities: ActivityEmployee[],
  { query }: { query: string }
): ActivityEmployee[] {
  return query
    ? entities.filter(
        (e) =>
          -1 < e.lastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(query?.toLowerCase()) ||
          -1 < e.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(query?.toLowerCase())
      )
    : entities;
}
```

Unfortunately, this search only works by name and surname. If I try to write "John Wessley" it doesn't find me any name, because he is looking for either John or Wessely.
How can I solve?

Comment: does it have to match exactly ?

Comment: No .. for example currently if I write "Jo" he shows me the fields with John and Johnatan, and as I write he refines my search.

Now let's imagine we have two Johns .. John Wessler and John Welbort ...

At that point I would also like to write the surname and refine the search also on the surname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the little information available in your question.

IF you are not looking for an exact match, you could concat the name and family name, and just check if the string you write match any of those.

```js
var employees = [{firstName : 'Jhon', lastName : 'Wick'},
{firstName : 'Miranda', lastName : 'Keyes'},
{firstName : 'Jhon', lastName : 'Cena'},
{firstName : 'Jhon', lastName : '117'},
{firstName : 'Robert', lastName : 'Deniro'},
{firstName : 'Wathever', lastName : 'is My Name'}]

function activityEmployeesFilterFn(
  entities,
  query
) {
  return query
    ? entities.filter(e => 
      `${e.firstName.toLowerCase()} ${e.lastName.toLowerCase()}`.includes(query.toLowerCase()))
    : entities;
}

console.log(activityEmployeesFilterFn(employees, 'Jhon'))
console.log(activityEmployeesFilterFn(employees, 'Jhon Cena'))
console.log(activityEmployeesFilterFn(employees, 'Jh'))
```

Comment: Type 'Activity[] | string[]' is not assignable to type 'Activity[]'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'Activity[]'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Activity'.ts(2322)

Comment: This is a problem with your typescript. and there is no `Activity` type shown in the question so I can't really help.

Comment: the answer is just how you could do, the implementation is probably differtent in your code. You might want to save the index (or the objext directly) of the item that matches, and return the entire `ActivityEmployee` has in my answer, I just return a string

Answer (score 0):

You can invert your comparative logic, so you'll search what was typed with first or last name.

```
-1 < query?.toLowerCase().indexOf(e.lastName.toLowerCase()) ||
-1 < query?.toLowerCase().indexOf(e.firstName.toLowerCase())
```

Comment: It doesn't work, because he currently searches only on  word given, so if I write John Weislerr he tries to look for "John Weislerr" either among the names or surnames, without distinguishing.